# Who created the Library?

Tags: the-magicians

Has it ever been explained in the books, TV or any other canon material as to who created the Library and who the first Librarian was?

Comment: https://themagicians.fandom.com/wiki/Library_of_the_Neitherlands

Comment: I saw that but is that an official wiki, it also doesn't go into a lot of detail

Comment: Indeed, and hence why I didn't post it as an answer. It was merely a comment.

Comment: I just re-read all the books and watched the entire series with this question in mind. Other than vague references about the flame of knowledge and *why* the Library is in the Neitherlands, nothing that I could find told the origin story of the Library. (that would be a really cool standalone, though)